# Reference request in relation with 'Yejamana krutham paapam Anna roopena thishtathi'

Tags: reference-request

> ..*Daanam Pratigraham* Chaiva Brahmanaanaamakalpayaat

Here, only Brahmana is entitled for **Pratigrham**-acceptance of Dhaana(Donation) from others,
(*though in tradition it is forbidden to receive by  demand*) reason being the observance of Gayathri Japa in routine that would protect from any sin incurred thru receiving.

Another saying in similar sense   (heard of) is

> **Yejamana krutham paapam
> Anna roopena thishtathi**
> (*Sin done by the Master , is imbibed in the food offered by that Master*)

Any scriptural  reference available for the above verse ?

Does any other veritable scriptural reference convey a similar sense?

Comment: From which sources are the former and latter sayings cited by you? Please give the name of the name of the texts and the verse no. where these exist.

Comment: Ok, I did find the source of the former verse, it's there in most of the Dharmaśāstras. It's firstly in Manusmr̥ti 10.75, and is mentioned in 10.74 as well. 
10.75: *adhyāpanamadhyayanaṁ yajanaṁ yājanaṁ tathā
dānaṁ pratigrahaścaiva śaṭ karmāṇyagrajamanaḥ*
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201811.html
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201810.html
The second link even gives the other dharmaśāstras and dharmasūtras where the similar verse occurs. It isn't the exact verse though.

Comment: But from which source is the latter saying from?

Comment: @Bingming , I've heard different traditional scholars , quoting the latter saying.
but  couldn't locate even a similar scriptural reference conveying the import.

Comment: I see. It might probably be just an oral cultural thing. Not all practices and sayings may have textual support to them.